# Can't find file to edit css contents of Python package I downloaded

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

I've downloaded the Trumbowyg WYSIWYG editor: http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/ as well as `django-trumbowyg` for integrating it with django: https://github.com/sandino/django-trumbowyg

I want to edit the editor by removing some buttons, changing colors/sizes etc. So to test it out I searched the package directory for `trumbowyg-button-pane`, which is the toolbar for the text editor (Bold, Italic, Underline etc). And there was only one result, a file called `trumbowyg.scss`. So I went into the file and found `.trumbowyg-button-pane`, and changed it to `display:none`. However it didn't change anything, as the toolbar still appears on my site. So now I'm not sure how else to edit the html/css of the package.

Not sure if it makes any difference, but the Trumbowyg WYSIWYG editor: http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/ (the front-end) is located in my `static/js`, wheras the `django-trumbowyg` (back-end) https://github.com/sandino/django-trumbowyg, which also has the same front-end directory in it (css, js files) is located in `site-packages`. However I don't think this is used as my `script` and `link` tags (for my js and css) point straight to those in my `static/js`.

If someone can suggest what the problem would be thad be great.

Comment: Try deleting your cache from your browser's history settings. That is most likely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the package, but unless you are running DEBUG=True, you may need to collectstatic: `python manage.py collectstatic` [as seen in the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the network tab in the console which showed a different css file being used, so I'm now able to edit the file.